Issue with ‘reticulate’ Not Recognizing ‘numpy’ Installation in R
I'm encountering an issue with the ‘reticulate’ package in R where it does not recognize my ‘numpy’ installation. Despite confirming that ‘numpy’ is correctly installed in my Python virtual environment and is accessible via Python scripts, ‘reticulate’ fails to import ‘numpy’, suggesting an environmental issue.
Environment:

macOS Sonoma 14.3.1
R version: 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Python version: 3.12.2
‘reticulate’ version: 1.35.0
Python Virtual Environment Path: ‘/Users/u/Python/bert_env’
’numpy’ version: 1.26.4

Steps taken

Confirmed ‘numpy’ installation in the virtual environment by running ‘python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.version)"‘ in the terminal, which outputs ‘1.26.4’.
In R, specified the Python interpreter with ‘reticulate::use_python("/Users/u/Python/bert_env/bin/python", required = TRUE)’.
Attempted to import ‘numpy’ using ‘reticulate::import("numpy", convert = FALSE)’, resulting in an import error.

Error Message:
Attempting to import ‘numpy’ results in the following error:
‘‘‘
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) :
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
your python interpreter from there.
Run ‘reticulate::py_last_error()’ for details.
‘‘‘
Additional Context:

The Python interpreter is a universal binary supporting both ‘x86_64’ and ‘arm64’ architectures.
The R session info indicates it's running on ‘x86_64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)’.
I have verified that the ‘PYTHONPATH’ environment variable is not set, which could potentially interfere with package detection.
A direct invocation of Python within the virtual environment successfully imports ‘numpy’ and confirms its version, suggesting that the Python setup and ‘numpy’ installation are correct.

I have followed standard troubleshooting steps, including specifying the virtual environment with both ‘use_python()’ and ‘use_virtualenv()’, checking environment variables, and ensuring there's no architecture mismatch between Python and R. However, the issue persists.
Any insights, suggestions, or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

This has nothing to do with python but rather R. consider installing the packages via R's interface. I believe in R studio you can directly type !pip install numpy and it should directly install numpy into the venv used by reticulate
